# Mud cannot be planted with Glowing Mushroom Seeds?

Tags: terraria

I have mud blocks in place under my house. I read somewhere that depth doesn't matter though. When I left click seeds above or onto the mud block, nothing happens.
Below is a screenshot for reference [image]

Comment: Is your farm built with Clay or Mud in the screenshot? I don't see very well, but according to the colour in the Terraria wiki, I am under the impression that you have mistaken both.

Comment: The screenshot has clay. Mud is brown-er... And darker... And gray-er.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Mushroom Grass Seeds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mushroom_Grass_Seeds) must be planted on [mud blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mud_Block).

Looking at your screenshot, it seems that you are trying to plant them on [clay blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clay), which will not work.

Mud blocks are darker than clay blocks

[image]              [image]

^ mud         ^ clay